# Funnel final step

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking

I'm pretty sure I made funnel correctly but for some reason final step work

Funnel visualization:

[image]

Funnel &Goals:

[image]

Comment: You have set "begins with" as match type but you use a regular expression (and if you set the match type to regexp you need to uses regular epxressions in you funnel steps as well).

Comment: can u please explain what is the first DESTINATION url? does it correspond to main goal? or should be entry point? thanks

Comment: "Destinantion" is your goal. The funnel steps are the necessary steps to get to your goal (which means that the destination url ist the last step in the funnel). If it's possible for visitors to skip funnel steps (e.g. going from step1 to step3 directly) Analytics will fill in the blanks (i.e. it will still report a hit for step2). If you look at the results in the interface you should look at the "Goal flow" view rather than the funnel, because goal flow shows when people skip steps or go backwards (the funnel view will simply report an exit when people step backwards).

Comment: Thanks! how do u form next goal queue in goal flow?